# How to know the max of this list of tuples? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, max

I okay so i need the max of this list:

```
variable=[[(0, 0), (0, 0)], [(0, 0), (0, 0)], [(0, 0), (0, 0)], [(13, '♠'), (13, '♣'), (3, '♠'), (3, '♥')], [(11, '♥'), (13, '♠'), (11, '♠'), (13, '♣')], [(11, '♥'), (13, '♠'), (11, '♣'), (13, '♣')]]
```

I´m using this line of code to do it but it doesn´t really work

```
print(max(variable,key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

The print says `[(13, '♠'), (13, '♣'), (3, '♠'), (3, '♥')]` but the one i need are one of the other two ones and i dont know what to do. Thanks in advance and sorry if i messed something up,this is my first time using stack overflow for asking a question. Im using python btw

Comment: You have a list of lists of varying length 2-tuples... what exactly does the "max" value mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `sum` of element `0` in your sub-list.

**Ex:**

```
variable=[[(0, 0), (0, 0)], [(0, 0), (0, 0)], [(0, 0), (0, 0)], [(13, '♠'), (13, '♣'), (3, '♠'), (3, '♥')], [(11, '♥'), (13, '♠'), (11, '♠'), (13, '♣')], [(11, '♥'), (13, '♠'), (11, '♣'), (13, '♣')]]
print(max(variable, key=lambda x: sum(i for i,_ in x)))
# --> [(11, '♥'), (13, '♠'), (11, '♠'), (13, '♣')]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this was it.